# Can't receive download requests from the QWebPage in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, mobile, download, qwebpage

I am trying to create a download manager for a QGraphicsWebView and so far it works good except one thing: I cannot send the download request from the QWebPage to the download manager.

```
QObject::connect(webPage, SIGNAL(downloadRequested(const QNetworkRequest&)),
                 this, SLOT(downloadRequested(const QNetworkRequest&)));
```

This is my code for connecting the download request signal to the slot that sends the request forward, to the download manager. I put a qDebug() message in the slot before the other actions and the message isn't displayed. This means the signal isn't sent when I click a link to a file.

Is there a way I could send a signal when the user clicks a link to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `downloadRequested(QNetworkRequest)` signal is only emitted when you right click on the link, and then click on the "Save link..." item of the context menu.

When the user clicks on a link to something that is supposed to be downloaded (with the HTTP field `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...`), `QWebPage` emits the   `unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply*)` signal.

Comment: What would I do if the file supposed to be download is a image file? it has the HTPP field `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...` but as I guess it's a supported file, `unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply*) ` isn't emited...

Comment: @Jack As specified in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#unsupportedContent) "This signal is only emitted if the [forwardUnsupportedContent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#forwardUnsupportedContent-prop) property is set to true.". But once that property is set, the signal should be emitted for all content defined as attachment.

Comment: That property is set to true, but the signal isn't emited for that files of image type albeit it does for PDF files. But I'd like to any kind of download.

Answer (score 1):

Look this: [QWebPage::unsupportedContent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#unsupportedContent)